# The Phragmén-Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr01.pdf  page 9, the following version of the Phragmén-Lindelöf theorem was proved. Can the bound $M$ be equal to zero? It's not clear in the statement of the theorem or the proof.

Theorem 1. We suppose that:

(i) $f$ is regular in the strip $a < x < b$; $f$  is continuous in $a \le  x \le b$

(ii) $| f | \le  M$ on $x = a$ and $x = b$

(iii) $f$ is bounded in  $a < x  < b$

Then, $| f | \le  M$ in  $a < x < b$; and $| f | = M$ in  $a< x <  b$ only if $f$ is a constant.

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the conclusion still follows for $M=0$... but/and if $|f|=0$ on any set with an accumulation point, then $f=0$ (on any connected set on which it's defined). That is, the $M=0$ case is degenerate.